# AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio: "System.Exception: Unable to determine project FileName" when Publishing to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-toolkit

When publishing my ASP.NET Core Web API to AWS using the AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio, the process fails with a `Timeout`  error.

After digging into the logs, I was able to find more detail:

```bash
2023-07-24 20:05:08,571 [9] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli - Finished initializing aws.deploy.tools
2023-07-24 20:05:18,534 [1] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.Lambda.LambdaTesterEventListener - Registering Debugger events
2023-07-24 20:05:18,563 [1] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.Lambda.LambdaTesterUtilities - Configuring Solution with Lambda Tester
2023-07-24 20:05:19,901 [1] ERROR Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.Lambda.LambdaTesterUtilities - Error configuring Lambda Tester on project. FileName: , FullName: , UniqueName: <MiscFiles>
System.Exception: Unable to determine project FileName
   at Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.Lambda.LambdaTesterUtilities.<EnsureLambdaTesterConfiguredAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Is there ea workaround? Is this a known issue in the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue in the AWS Tookit](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/issues/194#issuecomment-967328270).

The work-around is to delete the `PublishSettings.json` file located in Windows Explorer here:

```bash
%localappdata%\AWSToolkit\PublishSettings.json
```

Aside from that, to get out of this situation where you cannot access the more established publishing experience, delete the file and try opening the project's context menu again.